# Ubuntu desktop as a cloud service?

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization

I'm new to linux and to servers. I set up ubuntu 18.04 server on an old macbook to play with. I set up a website on it and then I decided to start again... on a real server. This time I want to virtualise using kvm.

My question is: 
Can I run an Ubuntu desktop inside one of the vm's and access it from a browser on any device? Seems to make sense to me, because, rather than have to have a computer turned on to access it I'd be running it on a server which is always on and it would have much more resources than my macbook ever had. I can't find anything on it though. May be that I'm looking in the wrong directions or using the wrong terminology though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `novnc` and access it from the web browser, see:

- [noVNC website](https://novnc.com/info.html)
- [How to use web browser as a VNC client](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262219/how-to-use-web-browser-as-vnc-client)
- [noVNC GitHub page](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC)